# Incorrect syntax near 'RDBMS'. When I try to create external data source, Anyone having the same issue?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

//I am using sql server 2017

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = '<servername>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'db1',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred
) ;
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server as the LOCATION, Do not use the TYPE parameter. This worked for me : USE [Test];
        CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [SQLDataSource]
            WITH (LOCATION = N'sqlserver://12.11.10.9', CREDENTIAL = [SqlServerCredentials]);

Answer (score 5):

> I am using sql server 2017

RDBMS External Data Sources are currently only supported on Azure SQL Database.

```
-- Elastic Database query only: a remote database on Azure SQL Database as data source   
-- (only on Azure SQL Database)  
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE data_source_name  
    WITH (   
        TYPE = RDBMS,  
        LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',  
        DATABASE_NAME = '<Remote_Database_Name>',  
        CREDENTIAL = <SQL_Credential>  
    )  
[;]
```

See [CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

On SQL Server 2017 you can use [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Adding to David answer. You can use the following tutorial to create a linked server to Azure http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0016.htm

Comment: @David, when an Azure SQL Database contains an RDBMS external table, it is not possible to generate a BACPAC file and import it into an on-prem SQL Server instance (eg for local development/testing). Is there a plan to add a fix/update to the BACPAC import process, so these tables can be skipped (instead of failing the import)?